# Sharepoint2010 performance

Tags: 2010, performance

We have Sharepoint2010Foundation  development like following.

- 1 windows2008 server x64 (Dbase and App Server)
- 8gb Ram and 4 Cpu on Virtual Environment

  Platform will be used over 600 users and we don't want to encounter speed or user problens sue to this reason we bought **a new server**.

  Which deployment suitable for us ? Do we chose dbase + App server model or is there any model can we use ?

  Best regards,

  Ossy

Comment: Is this production or single dev enviroment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of how Microsoft would have you set up your environment, by size.

Small - (1) database server and (1+) front end servers

Medium - (1) database server, (2) application servers, (2) front end servers. Application server hosts Central Administration

Large - (2+) database, clustered or mirrored, several load balanced front end servers, (2+) application servers. Every application server can be assigned a specific service application or service application components

These scenarios would not be possible on one physical server, unless you were creating virtual machines on it.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from hardware some software tools can also be used which are really effective in enhancing SharePoint performance and scalability.

I believe there are lot of problems that contribute to performance bottlenecks in SharePoint however it is a very useful extremely popular product that improves effectiveness of organizations through content management and enterprise search, shared business processes, and information-sharing across boundaries for better business insight.

The SharePoint performance problems occur primarily due to the following reasons:

- BLOBs overwhelm SQL Server
- Too many database trips for lists

You can dramatically improve SharePoint performance if you use a few of intelligent techniques which are:

- Externalize Documents (BLOBs)
- Cache Lists and BLOBs

StorageEdge provides precisely such a blob caching facility. It offers a unique combination of externalization and BLOB caching for effective blob management and access from a single interface. It makes use of NCache® technology to let you cache frequently used BLOBs in a distributed fashion with high availability, complete replication and failover. A distributed cache can give your SharePoint infrastructure a significant scalability boost because it keeps things distributed across multiple servers and still giving one logical view. But the cache actually lives on multiple servers and that’s what allows the cache to really scale.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say "for X number of users you need this Y amount of RAM and Z amount of CPU cores".

First of all you need to analyze what will you use SharePoint for; you say it's SharePoint Foundation so I assume it is collaboration in some small manner. How much documents, sites, lists etc do you anticipate?

Secondly, how will you customize it; what kind of customizations, only small UI changes or more advanced development customizations?

The questions are many - but for any kind of production scenario I would go for two machines one SharePoint and one SQL box and at least the minimum required specs (according to MSFT). Then I always test, test and stress-test before going live...